# Make items equal to widest column and center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two cells side by side.

The cells are bounded by an inner container and that container is bound by an outer container.

The idea is for the two cells to be equal width, even though their content isn't.

The width of each cell must be the width of the widest element.

The inner container will then be centered (width should be twice the widest cell).

At the moment I have two results:

1. They are the same width but extend to half the available page width.
2. The inner container shrinks to the center but the cells are uneven
   in width.

Is it possible to achieve what I want without javascript?

```css
body {
  background-color: lime;
}
.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.fb {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.fb-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    /* flex: 0; */
    
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 0.1rem rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
.fb-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;

    color: rgba(0,0,0, .87);
    font-size: 14px;    height: 46px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}

.fb-item:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="fb">
        <div class="fb-container">
            <div class="fb-item">
                <span class="fb_label">Much longer</span>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-item">
                <span class="fb_label">Short</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more suitable for CSS grid. You can keep the flexbox for centring.

```css
body {
  background-color: lime;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.fb {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fb-container {
  display: grid; /* Added this */
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* Added this */
  /* to replace the middle border*/
  grid-gap:1px;
  background:#e6e6e6 padding-box;
  /* */
  border: solid 0.1rem #e6e6e6;
}

.fb-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fb">
    <div class="fb-container">
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Much loooooonger</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Short</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or a hacky idea with flexbox that I don't recommend:

```css
body {
  background-color: lime;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.fb {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fb-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column; /* This will make them both equal */
  transform:translateX(-50%); /* Hack */
}

.fb-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  background:#fff;
  border: solid 0.1rem rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
.fb-item:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: none;
  transform:translateY(-100%) translateX(100%);  /* Hack */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fb">
    <div class="fb-container">
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Much loooooooonger</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Short</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In an ideal world, yes! However, it's taken 10 years for browsers to get to grips with flexbox, and there's just not version support for grid yet.

Comment: @JohnOhara almost all the browser support Grid: https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid even IE support it with prefixes

Comment: Latest versions perhaps. IE supports and older version, and iOS/Safari only started supporting from 2017 - that's not enough for a production version.

Comment: @JohnOhara I added a *hacky* way because I don't think there is a clean solution without CSS grid

Comment: Could the hack work with more than 2 cells ? I guess a javascript solution for his needs wouldn't be so bad after all this.

Comment: @Niloct yes it can work with more than 2 : https://jsfiddle.net/nyjL9u05/ but the question is about 2

Comment: Understood the trick. Making `flex-direction: column` makes all cells same width, and then you translate each cell.

Comment: Well, I don't know where that idea came from, but it does work. What's more, it's only ever so slightly hacky. Given that no legit answer seems to exist, other than CSS Grid, I think this is the best we will do today.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the items the same size but not conditionally sized with css, just set the width to 0 so that flex listens to the grow rather than the text.

```
div {
  display:flex;
}

div div {
  flex-grow:1;
  border :1px solid black;
  width:0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/logan-murphy/pen/ewyqQG

Comment: The essential part of the code should be _within_ the answer, not as an external link, and the reason is for this answer to be useful after such external link die.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this is one of the outputs I'm getting at the moment.

Comment: display:table is also made for that kind of behavior, not flex  : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RzQWwp  ... if you want to include older browser

Answer (score 0):

It also looks to me like a typical table-layout (via `display:table`) *without any hack and should be avalaible down to IE8*:

> `table-layout` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
>
> **auto**
>
> By default, most browsers use an automatic table layout algorithm. The widths of the table and its cells are adjusted to fit the content.
>
> **fixed**
>
> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.
>
> Under the "fixed" layout method, the entire table can be rendered once the first table row has been downloaded and analyzed. This can speed up rendering time over the "automatic" layout method, but subsequent cell content might not fit in the column widths provided. Cells use the overflow property to determine whether to clip any overflowing content, `but only if the table has a known width;` otherwise, they won't overflow the cells.

DEMO :

```css
body {
  background-color: lime;
}

.container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.fb {/* can be removed  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  */
}

.fb-container {
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;/* reset table-layout */
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

.fb-item {
  display: table-cell;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .87);
  width: 50%;/* make cols same width , adjust to numbers of ccols */
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 46px;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.fb-item:not(:first-child) {
  border-left: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fb">
    <div class="fb-container">
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Much longer</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Short</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="fb">
    <div class="fb-container">
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Much much longer</span>
      </div>
      <div class="fb-item">
        <span class="fb_label">Short</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```